# How does the function **called by** setInterval() access the variables of the enclosing function, after the enclosing function returns?

Tags: javascript, scope, setinterval

My understanding of Javascript is that once a function is done with its job, the local variables of that function are then discarded. However, consider the following code:

```
document.onkeydown = function Encloser(evt){
    evt = evt || window.event;
    switch(evt.keyCode){
        case 88:
            var x = 50;
            var intrvl = setInterval(function Enclozee(){
                console.log(x);
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
                actionRoutine(x--);
                if(x < 0)
                    clearInterval(intrvl);
            }, 50);
            break;
    }
    // Redraw Routine
    console.log(evt.keyCode);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    actionRoutine(50);
    console.log("returning now");
};
```

The `Enclozee`, which gets called every 50ms, accesses the variable `x` and `intrvl` from inside it, but these actions take place long after `Encloser` has returned (by logging `returning now` on the console). How is it possible? Is the `Encloser` making the garbage collector wait? Is this behavior unsafe? And how does the primitive type `x` not get removed from the function stack after the `Encloser` function returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concept is known as a "closure". While some languages do wipe all local variables when the call stack finishes, javascript is not one of them. Variables are safe from garbage collection as long as there is a route from the root of memory to that variable.

So as long as something still refers to that inner function, any variables used by the inner function will not be collected. In this case, it's the internal code of setInterval which keeps the reference to the inner function, and it will continue to do so until you call clearInterval. After that point, there are no more references to the function, so it can be garbage collected along with the variables it references.

Comment: Is there a function stack in javascript implementations, or do all the variables (including primitives) go to heap? Also, in case the stack exists, does the garbage collector take care of variables of stack as well?

Comment: It's up to the browser or javascript engine (i'm not sure which) to decide where to allocate the variable. They have optimisation which will allocate the variable to the stack if possible, or heap if it's not. As a developer, all you need to know is that if you write code that refers to the variable, it will be available to you (ie, on the heap). What happens to variables you never use is up to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe

This is because when the `Enclozee` is created, it also creates a **closure**, allowing it to access all variables that were in the scope at the time of its creation, even after their original context has ended

You can read more about it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures